# Customizing cursor images in scrolling div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, cursor

I have a div that scrolls content when the cursor is either at the top or bottom (scrolling up or down). I have two customized cursor images- one is supposed to show when the div content is scrolling up and the other when the div content is scrolling down. The script below was written by a stackoverflow member and works only when using standard cursor styles such as wait, pointer, etc. I want to use images, but cannot get it to work correctly. I also do not need the timer in the script below.

```
 <script type='text/javascript' >
 var top=0, timer;

 $('#repertoirescroll').on('scroll', function() {
 clearTimeout(timer);
 var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
    cursor = scrollTop > top ? 'pointer' : 'wait';
 $('body').css('cursor', cursor);
 top = scrollTop;
 timer = setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
 }, 500);
 });​

 </script>
```

The image names I am using are

```
 url(../images/arrowup.png)
 url(../images/arrowdown.png)
```

*HTML/CSS**

```
 .cursorup {
  cursor: url(../images/arrowup.png), auto;
  position:relative;

 }

 .cursordown {
  cursor: url(../images/arrowdown.png), auto;
  position:relative;

 }
```

scrolling content

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Can you set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1):

To use custom cursors, you use CSS styling:

```
.curarrowup {
    cursor: url(../images/arrowup.png), auto;
}
```

Then to apply, use jQuery to apply the style:

```
$(myElement).addClass("curarrowup");
```

When you want to go back to a normal cursor:

```
$(myElement).removeClass("curarrowup");
```

Using $('body') (myElement === 'body') as in your example is fine.

One caveat: in Firefox, the new cursor often will not appear until you actually move the mouse.  This is a known bug and I cannot find any workarounds.

**Edit:** Modifying your code:

```
var top=0, timer;

$('#repertoirescroll').on('scroll', function() {
    var scrollTop, cursor;

    clearTimeout(timer);
    scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    cursor = scrollTop > top ? 'curarrowup' : 'curarrowdown';
    $('body').addClass(cursor);
    top = scrollTop;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').removeclass(cursor);
    }, 500);
});​
```

Comment: Thank you. Any chance you can show me how to implement this in the code I already have above?

Comment: Without your HTML I can't be 100% sure, but I made a stab at it.

Comment: Could not get this to work...I have edited to show HTML/CSS. And I am using your javascript exactly as it is (except that it says cursorup and cursordown). Do I need to add any css style to the div or any additional plugins?

Comment: You need the CSS classes for the cursor that match the names.  If you want more in-depth help, use jsFiddle.net to set up a fiddle and post the link here.

Comment: Thanks, they do match the names. I will try to set up a fiddle and post back.

Comment: Oh, I tried with the fiddle for over an hour...not sure how to work that thing lol

Comment: Hmm, sorry then.  I can't diagnose why this doesn't work for you without something to run.  Do you have it on the public web somewhere maybe?

Comment: I took a quick look -- there a lot of stuff there and I can't make a copy easily to check, but I suggest two things first: 1) Make sure the scroll event is being fired (add something like console.log("Got here scroll!") and use a dev console like Firebug to see that it gets there.  2) Make sure your custom cursors work.  In your document ready function, add the class to the body and see that that works.  If it doesn't your cursor is not being found, or the file is bad.

Comment: Thanks. I added the cursor images directly to the div and they do work...javascript is just not working

Comment: Thanks for trying Ares...I cannot get it to work. Going to scratch this.

Comment: What do you mean the div?  Aren't you trying to add them to the body?  Also, did you ensure the scroll event is being triggered?

Comment: I am trying to add the cursors to a div called #repertoirescroll Yes, the scroll event is being triggered